# Help with BURG on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, bootloader, burg

Can anyone tell me if [this article for BURG Boot-loader](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/beautiful-burg-boot-loader-gets-ubuntu-11-04-ppa/) is correct? I'm sure it is due to the fact that I have never had a problem with the site before. But I am always weary of things made for older versions of Ubuntu.

Keep in mind I have 12.04 not 11.04. Could the same be applied for 12.04 or are they completely different. If so, could you give me a step by step guide of what to do in order to get BURG up and running on my 12.04 computer?

It also says to be completely sure of what I'm doing and how to reverse it. I know that I'm messing with my boot-loader, meaning, if I mess up, I would have basically no way of booting any operating system and would have to install Ubuntu all over again in order to get back to the original boot-loader. (Or, at least, that is what happened before (not when trying to change loaders, just when I accidentally turned off my computer while Ubuntu was in start-up.) But, I do not know any way to reverse the process if something were to go wrong.

I dual-boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 only, side-by-side.

My Ubuntu partition is named /dev/sda4, and (according to GParted,) contains /dev/sda6 (file system: ext4) and /dev/sda4 (file system: linux-swap). My Windows 7 partition is /dev/sda3. This information was given so you don't have to say "replace "blah" with your hard drive name," or anything like that. I do not want to mess anything up.

Even if it is all correct for Ubuntu 12.04, I'd like you to rewrite it so any simpleton anywhere knows exactly what to do. (No definitions needed.) Please and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tut on the link you provided looks fine. If you mess up the boot loader you do NOT need to do a full install again. You can reinstall grub using a live CD or something like Super GRUB Disk.

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
- ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes grub-customizer
- sudo burg-install "(hd0)" 
  [Or (sda)]
- sudo burg-emu
  (to test it out)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that elsewhere, but I wasn't sure what they meant by it, they gave no alternative from the clean install. I just looked up Super Grub2 Disk. Can it be used with a USB instead of a CD?

Comment: DO a search for 'fix grub live ubuntu cd'. There are a bazillion helpful guides made by Ubuntu fanss and users out there.

Comment: Hi, think if I messed up my GRUB in kubuntu 12.04. Will I can recover it using the step above you stated or using the live CD.

Comment: Live cd is the best way to go - but the burg will fix it too.

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell is that the burg package from ppa:n-muench/burg still works in 12.04.

I had Ubuntu 11.04 with burg installed and working, and I recently went through the (somewhat painful) upgrade to 12.04. 
Although the upgrade installed and configured the latest grub, after a simple 'burg-upgrade' operation I was able to get burg back to work, including also the saved theme.